# Converting Special Characters with PHP

Tags: php, string, special-characters

I am trying to turn a standard wordpress title into a slug, that makes all characters lowercase, replaces spaces with dashes, and removes all "&" symbols that are in the titles.

So lets use this title as an example: "**Identity & Wayfinding**"

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php 
$title = get_the_title(); 
$lower = strtolower($title);
$noDash = str_replace(' ', '-', $lower);
$noAnd = str_replace('&', '', $noDash);
echo $noAnd;
?>
```

This turns my title into "**identity-#038;-wayfinding**"

The lowercase conversion worked, but the replacing of the"&" with nothing isnot working . It is converting the "&" into an HTML special character. Any idea how I can simply replace the "&" with a blank, but also REMOVE the dash after that so the final title would be: **"identity-wayfinding"**?

Comment: What's wrong with using [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983989/convert-ascii-to-utf-8-encoding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a slug, there are plenty of utilities which will do it for you, but neither htmlentities or urlencode is correct. Doctrine 1.2 included a `urlizer` class with a set of static functions including `urilize` which will accomplish the behavior you desire in a more robust manner (handles UTF-8 and unaccenting correctly, etc.)

It can be found [here](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Sluggable/Util/Urlizer.php)

If you want something less robust but far simpler:

```
function slugify($sluggable)
{
    $sluggable = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $sluggable);
    $sluggable = trim($sluggable, '-');
    if( function_exists('mb_strtolower') ) { 
        $sluggable = mb_strtolower( $sluggable );
    } else { 
        $sluggable = strtolower( $sluggable );
    }
    $sluggable = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", '-', $sluggable);

    return $sluggable;
}
```

That'll strip non-alphanumeric characters (but also accented characters) and make spaces, + signs, and hyphens into hyphens.

Comment: I do not want to use urilize because it requires using this php file, which seems unnecessary for this simple change

Comment: I got: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_strtolower()

Comment: You don't have php_mbstring. Use strtolower in place of mb_strtolower or use the updated code in my post

Comment: this leaves me with "interpretive-038-donor" I want the 038- gone!

Comment: In that case, you're running htmlentities on the title before outputting it! You need to call `$blah = html_entity_decode($title);` before running the function i gave you.

Comment: As htmlentities() is the wrong function. html_entity_decode is the inverse operation.

Comment: wait,    nvm. (15 chars comment).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) by first removing the " "(space), then "-" and then replacing the & with dash.

```
$title = "Identity & Wayfinding";
$title = strtolower(str_replace(array(" ","-","&"),array("","","-"),$title));

echo $title; // returns: identity-wayfinding
```

[Example@viper7](http://codepad.viper-7.com/MIzhIJ).

Comment: He doesn't want either of those functions...he wants a slug.

Comment: Indeed. He doesn't want `#038;`, he wants that character stripped.

Comment: htmlentitie does not remove the special chars

Comment: #Omeid - this doesnt get rid of the "#038;"

Comment: still the same problem with your code, but answer above works great!

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is, did you check the Example ? the output is plain text. what "#038" are you talking about ?

Comment: it seems to be working fine in your example, but when I use it I still see the problem. Thanks for your help +1, but above solution works better for me

Answer (score 0):

You are probably talking about slugs, see these:

- [Slug URL generation function overriding the Ç](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183010/slug-url-generation-function-overriding-the)
- [best way to escape and create a slug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580581/best-way-to-escape-and-create-a-slug) (and the article linked in it)
- or any of the previously linked answers [SEO Friendly links, js and/or php stripping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758881/seo-friendly-links-js-and-or-php-stripping) here

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
 <?php
function create_slug($string){
$slug=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $string);
$slug=ltrim($slug, "-");
$slug=rtrim($slug, "-");
return strtolower($slug);
}
echo create_slug('does this thing work or not');
//returns 'does-this-thing-work-or-not'

echo "<br />";
echo create_slug('"Identity & Wayfinding"');
?>
```

[Live Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fk7Fnl)

Of course if you want to use this function in Wordpress, you just need to use this:

```
<?php sanitize_title( $title, $fallback_title ) ?>
```

Where, `$title` is the input string & `$fallback_title` is the default value, if `$title` comes out empty. Read more here: [Wordpress Function Reference/Sanitize Title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function I use.

```
function text_as_url($str='', $separator = 'dash', $lowercase = false){
    if ($separator == 'dash'){
        $search     = '_';
        $replace    = '-';
    } else {
        $search     = '-';
        $replace    = '_';
    }

    $trans = array(
                    '\/'                    => '-',
                    '&\#\d+?;'              => '-',
                    '&\S+?;'                => '-',
                    '\s+'                   => $replace,
                    '[^a-z0-9\-\._]'        => '', // accents
                    $replace.'+'            => $replace,
                    $replace.'$'            => $replace,
                    '^'.$replace            => $replace,
                    '\.+$'                  => '-'
                );

    $str = strip_tags($str);

    foreach ($trans as $key => $val){
        $str = preg_replace("#".$key."#i", $val, $str);
    }

    if($lowercase === true){
        $str = strtolower($str);
    }

    return trim(stripslashes($str));
}
```